# Is there any evidence of other Metamorphmagi in Tonks's family?

Tags: harry-potter

Here's what happens to Teddy Lupin after being born, in Remus' words:

> "Not much hair. It looked black when he was born, but I swear it's turned ginger in the hour since. Probably blonde by the time I get back. Andromeda says Tonks's hair started changing colour the day that she was born."

And here's what Tonks says to Harry:

> Metamorphmagi are really rare, they're born, not made.

I'm concluding that, however rare, there is some gene that Tonks has and is passed on to Teddy.  The wiki, though, only lists Tonks and Teddy as Metamorphmagi. Is there any evidence of past Metamorphmagi in Tonks's family?

Comment: When you say "there is some gene that Tonks has and is passed on to Lupin" do you mean Teddy Lupin, or Remus Lupin?

Comment: @Au101 it could only possibly be Teddy Lupin.

Comment: Imagine a mother marrying a son...

Answer (score 2):

There is no evidence to suggest that any members of Tonks family being metamorphmagi. The only explicit ones in the book are Tonks, of course, and Teddy Lupin, her son.

Tonk's father was muggle born, her mother is the pure-blood sister of Bellatrix Lestrange and Malcoy's mother Narcissa, none of which being a metemorphmagus. But it could be possible that somewhere higher up in the family tree there are more metamorphmagi (though there is no evidence to confirm nor deny this).